# Django Rest Framework Validate Child in ListField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a list of DictField instances.
Here is my serializer.py

```
class DetailSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
"""Serialize order"""
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    order= serializers.IntegerField(min_value=1)

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orderlist = DetailSerializer(many=True)
```

Now I want to do validation for orderlist like make sure every order in this list is strictly_increasing. How can I do?

Comment: you can [writing-custom-validators](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#writing-custom-validators) for example, and if you catch troubles then write your question

Answer (score 0):

You can define your validation logic by overriding the `validate` method in `OrderSerializer`. The official documentation explains it very well (read "Object-level validation"): http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation

In your case, it would look something like this:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orderlist = DetailSerializer(many=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        # custom validation logic here
```

Calling `is_valid()` for an instance of order serializer then will invoke the `validate` method with your custom logic and inform you of any errors.